# How to fix .NET7 NETSDK1194 error in an upgraded project?

Tags: azure-functions, .net-7.0

I upgraded a few Azure functions from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 7. Now I see this warning. How can I fix this?

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.304\Current\SolutionFile\ImportAfter\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Solution.targets(36,5): warning NETSDK1194: The "--output" option isn't supported when building a solution. Specifying a solution-level output path results in all projects copying outputs to the same directory, which can lead to inconsistent builds. [C:\My Projects__**_**\api.sln]

Answer (score 1):

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.304\Current\SolutionFile\ImportAfter\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Solution.targets(36,5): warning NETSDK1194: The "--output" option isn't supported when building a solution. Specifying a solution-level output path results in all projects copying outputs to the same directory, which can lead to inconsistent builds. [C:\My Projects__**_**\api.sln]

This occurs due to changes in the supported flags for .NET 7 when building the solutions.

***Try below fixes:***

**Fix 1:**

Instead of  `-o` dir /  `--output` dir, use  `--property:OutputPath=DIR` as shown below:

[image]

**Fix 2:**

Use `--output` in project level instead of solution level.

- As mentioned in this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/7.0/solution-level-output-no-longer-valid), there is a change in .NET 7 to no longer accept the  `--output`/`-o`  option when using a solution file with build command.
- When using  `--output` dir /`-o` dir a solution file in previous versions, the output for all the built projects would be placed in the specified directory in an undefined order.
- Now,  `dotnet`  CLI throws error occurs if `--output`/`-o` option is placed within the solution file. In case of `dotnet pack` no warning or error will occur.

***References:***

For detailed information regarding the error & fix, refer [Solution-level  `--output`  option no longer valid for build-related commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/7.0/solution-level-output-no-longer-valid)

Comment: I don't know where to make the change. What I have is a SLN file which has a list of Azure functions. The solution file doesn't have a section where I can specify the ```--property:OutputPath=DIR``` option. The build settings are read from ```C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.304\Current\SolutionFile\ImportAfter\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Solution.targets(36,5)```

Comment: Go to this path `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.304\Current\SolutionFile\ImportAfter\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Solution.targets`. Open `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Solution.targets` file and check if you have `--output` in that file. Refer [image](https://i.imgur.com/WfZsvWr.png)

Comment: I don't see ```---output``` in the file. My file is exactly the same as you see in the image that you just added.

Comment: Can you run `dotnet build` and check if you are getting the same warning

Comment: I'm not getting any error when run the command ```dotnet build```.